# Accessing user scripts directory in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, nsfilemanager, appstore-sandbox

I want my app to be able to execute some user scripts which can be installed in the app-specific user scripts directory (like `~/Library/Application Scripts/appbundleidentifier`), but `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationScriptsDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error]` only works in Mountain Lion as `NSApplicationScriptsDirectory` was introduced with Mountain Lion. How can I find this directory under Mac OS X Lion? The app is sandboxed, so hardcoding the path is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe flat-out this feature doesn't exist in 10.7, so the folder doesn't exist, so you can't "find" it.